# VoltDB - Writing your own client or using JSON HTTP Interface

Tags: voltdb

I am a bit confused in how should I perform my operation using `VoltDB`. There are two choice -

1. Run `VoltDB` server, create a connection from the client and call your required procedure.
2. JSON HTTP Interface provided by the `VoltDB` itself.

I have different applications which need to access the data stored in `VoltDB`, So I was writing code to connect and call required procedures, but later when I read about JSON HTTP Interface provided by the `VoltDB` I realized that the data can be accessed over the HTTP APIs without connecting each application with `VoltDB`.

Now I am confused which method should I choose and why?

I am pretty much in favor of using HTTP APIs provided by `VoltDB`. But what are the implications of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is pretty straightforward.

If you have a situation where low latency is high priority, for example,

1. storing/processing real-time data which can go to a high rate of transactions/sec.
2. High insertion rates.
3. High data query rates.

Then using a real client will typically be the best solution, since you can have a persistent connection.  This is not possible with the HTTP API, which needs to reconnect and re-authenticate for each call and use HTTP API for operational queries like fetching/storing data which has low hits.